# Org-mode maxima code-blocks incorrect syntax

Tags: emacs, org-mode, maxima

I'm new to Emacs, coming from Vim, using Spacemacs on Windows 10 atm. My problem is that when I try to evaluate maxima code blocks in emacs, for example:

```
#+begin_src maxima
a: 1+1;
print(a);
#+end_src
```

I get the following error:

```
#+RESULTS:
 "incorrect syntax:  / is not a prefix operator"
```

I think it might be because of how windows is handling the path. I found the following code online and replaced it in "ob-maxima.el" but it didn't help:

```
(let* ((cmdline (or (cdr (assoc :cmdline params)) ""))
          (in-file (org-babel-temp-file "maxima-" ".max"))
        (cmd (format "%s --very-quiet -r \"batchload(\\\"%s\\\")$\" %s"
                 org-babel-maxima-command in-file cmdline)))
```

Thanks a lot for you help, much appreciated!

Edit 2020.03.26---------------------
I got it working using "choco install maxima", now it executes properly.

Comment: You can answer your own question